# Arima на всех обучающих параметрах выдает value error

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, временные-ряды

Всем привет!
Я только начинаю пробовать применять класс моделей arima, поэтому возможно вопрос кому-то покажется глупым. Но..
На переборе всевозможных параметров p, q, P, Q, модель выдает value error:wrong  parameters, что значит, что она не может обучиться ни на одном. Я не могу понять причину. Код ниже.

```
results = []
best_aic = float("inf")
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
ex_regressors=data[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]]

for param in parameters_list:
    #try except нужен, потому что на некоторых наборах параметров модель не обучается  exog= ex_regressors
    try: 
        model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data['y'][8:], order=(param[0], d, param[1]), 
                                        seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], 365)).fit(disp=-1)
    #выводим параметры, на которых модель не обучается, и переходим к следующему набору
    except ValueError:
        print('wrong parameters:', param)
        continue
    aic = model.aic
    #сохраняем лучшую модель, aic, параметры
    if aic < best_aic:
        best_model = model
        best_aic = aic
        best_param = param
    results.append([param, model.aic])

warnings.filterwarnings('default')
```

Comment: вы можете привести пример данных и параметров, которые позволят воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: @MaxU данные - это подневной временной ряд, загруженный из excel, их как-то можно сюда прикрепить? параметры

Comment: перебор всех комбинаций вот этих чисел ps = range(0, 3)
d=1
qs = range(0, 2)
Ps = range(0, 8)
D=1
Qs = range(0, 12)

Comment: данные можно выложить на любой бесплатный файлообменник и указать ссылку на него...

Comment: @MaxU https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CiwhupocypMabkroXYkpTF8J8hl94Npt/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: я никогда не работал с ARIMA/SARIMAX, поэтому не совсем понимаю назначение коэффициентов (`p`,`d`,`q` и `P`,`D`,`Q`,`s`).

чтение данных:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\download\arima data.xlsx')
```

я попробовал обучить модель со следующими коэффициентами:

```
model = SARIMAX(data['y'].iloc[8:], order=(1,0,0), seasonalq_order=(1,1,1,365))
model.fit(disp=True)
```

---

```
model = SARIMAX(data['y'].iloc[8:], order=(1,1,1), seasonalq_order=(1,1,1,365))
model.fit(disp=True)
```

---

```
model = SARIMAX(data['y'].iloc[8:], order=(1,1,1), seasonalq_order=(5,1,6,365))
model.fit(disp=True)
```

все три варианта отработали без ошибок...

PS

```
In [431]: statsmodels.__version__
Out[431]: '0.9.0'
```

Comment: Спасибо, думаю, дело было в версии statsmodels (0.8.0 была у меня). Пока, правда, проверить не могу, обновила, но сейчас memory error:(

Comment: @Lyudmila, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Есть  такая библиотека `pmdarima`. А в ней есть функция `auto_arima` -  как раз для вашего случая. Перебор различных (из заданных диапазонов) значений всех коэффициентов `SARIMA` (и трендовых и сезонных) и поиск среди них такого набора, который дает минимизацию ошибки. Рекомендую попробовать. По крайней мере, не надо самому циклы гонять.